# Is there any way to make ferrofluids float on water?

Tags: magnetism

I am trying to do an oil spill clean up experiment, and I was thinking of using magnetism to clean up oil. I could make a ferrofluid/ferripaste using some type of oil, such as motor oil or mineral oil, and iron oxide or magnetite powder. I don't want it to sink in the water because if we used this in real life, you don't want the oil to sink in the ocean. Here is the video on how to make ferrofluid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CWH9C__jn2w.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using a froth of bubbles? You could try adding a bit of detergent to the ferrofluid and use an aquarium bubbler to see:

1. Does this create froth?
2. Will that froth (if it is created) float?
3. Will it draw in added oil?
4. Can magnets remove this from the water?
5. Can the excess oil be removed to **regenerate the original ferrofluid**?

Without step 5, your idea would be economically unfeasible.